# Search items of one table into another save the results

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

```
Table 1

+--------+-----+-----+  
| name   | id1 | id2 |   
+--------+-----+-----+    
| luis   | 1   | 1.2 |  
+--------+-----+-----+   
| carlos | 2   | 1.3 |  
+--------+-----+-----+  
| george | 3   | 1.5 |  
+--------+-----+-----+   

Table 2

+--------+-----+-----+  
| points | id1 | id2 |  
+--------+-----+-----+   
| 100    | 1   | 1.2 |  
+--------+-----+-----+   
| 50     | 6   | 2   |   
+--------+-----+-----+   
| 48     | 3   | 1.5 |   
+--------+-----+-----+
```

I want to search all the cases when id1 and id2 are equal in both tables and save the records of the second table in a new one.

For this case it will be:

```
Table 3

+--------+-----+-----+   
| points | id1 | id2 |   
+--------+-----+-----+   
| 100    | 1   | 1.2 |        
+--------+-----+-----+   
| 48     | 3   | 1.5 |       
+--------+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT ...` syntax and `JOIN` `table1` and `table2` with `id1` and `id2`:

```
CREATE TABLE Table3 AS
SELECT Table2.*
FROM Table2
JOIN Table1
ON Table2.id1 = Table1.id1
AND Table2.id2 = Table2.id2;
```

[**SqlFiddle Demo Here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1fac8/1).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `exists` or an `inner join` to do this.

```
insert into table3(points,id1,id2)
select points,id1,id2
from table2 t2
where exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t1.id1=t2.id1 and t1.id2=t2.id2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE table3 AS
 SELECT table1.points, table1.id1, table2.id2
 FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id1 = table2.id1 AND table1.id2 = table2.id2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the exists is a bit much, but it works. For what you are asking, it would be much simpler to just INNER JOIN the two tables.

```
INSERT INTO `table3` (points, id1, id2)  
SELECT bar.points, bar.id1, bar.id2 
FROM bar 
INNER JOIN foo ON bar.id1 = foo.id1
  AND bar.id2 = foo.id2
;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/424ede/1

Comment: Oops. Just realized two people beat me with essentially the same answer. Should have refreshed.

Answer (score 0):

Using the SQL `INSERT INTO SELECT` Statement and the `LEFT JOIN`: Get the corresponding details from `table2`, where its `id1` and `id2` corespond to the values in `table1`, and insert them in a third table (`table3`):

```
INSERT INTO table3 AS t3 (points, id1, id2)
SELECT 
    t2.points,
    t2.id1,
    t2.id2
FROM table2 AS t2
LEFT JOIN table1 AS t1 ON (t1.id1 = t2.id1 AND t1.id2 = t2.id2);
```